# Android: Dialog Builder multipleselection setting array

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I'm trying to follow the android docs about multiple selection dialog boxes. I'm having an issue, and I think it's with the type of arrays i'm trying to load in.

```
public void addCondition(View view){

         ArrayList<String> mHelperNames= new ArrayList<String>();
           mHelperNames.add("Test Item");
           mHelperNames.add("Test Item");
           mHelperNames.add("Test Item");


           mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("My Title")
                   .setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames, null,
                              new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                               boolean isChecked) {
                           if (isChecked) {

                               mSelectedItems.add(which);
                           } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {

                               mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                           }
                       }
                   })

                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //Create onlcick method
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //Create onlcick method
                       }
                   });
            builder.show();

    }
```

Above is my code, but it's red-line city in eclipse:

[image]

In the docs, mSelectedItems is never declared, and I'm not too sure what I'm declaring it as.

The error on .SetMultipleChoiceItems is:

The method setMultiChoiceItems(int, boolean[], DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){})

But if i change it from a string, how do I show text items in it? Any help will be really appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must provide a `CharSequence[]` to `setMultiChoiceItems` method, not an `ArrayList`.

You could create `mHelperNames` like this:

```
CharSequence[] mHelperNames = new CharSequence[] { "test item 1", "test item 2" };
```

And don't forget to declare `mSelectedItems` too:

```
final List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

(It has to be final because you access it from an inner class)

You can also keep `mHelperNames` as an ArrayList if you need to modify it later. Then you need to convert it to an array when calling `setMultiChoiceItems`:

```
    List<CharSequence> mHelperNames = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    mHelperNames.add("Test Item 1");
    mHelperNames.add("Test Item 2");

    final List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("My Title")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(mHelperNames.toArray(new CharSequence[mHelperNames.size()]), null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {

                                mSelectedItems.add(which);
                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {

                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer
                                        .valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: You sir, are welcome for dinner at my house anytime. Thank you. One quick question, how would I add to a charsequence elsewhere and not a static list at the start?